# Rstudio does not recognize MacTeX MacOSx 10.7.5, can't preview pdf

Tags: r, rstudio, miktex

I have created an .md file, but to preview it in pdf format Rstudio requires MacTeX installation. I've installed it, read README file, everything is there, the Terminal shows all packages, BUT Rstudio doesn't see, and produces the message below. How can I sync both programs? How to make Rstudio detect that MacTeX is there?

```
--to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output HelloWorld.pdf --template /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default.tex --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable 'geometry:margin=1in'
pandoc: pdflatex not found. pdflatex is needed for pdf output.
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 41
Execution halted

No TeX installation detected (TeX is required to create PDF output). You should install a recommended TeX distribution for your platform:

  Windows: MiKTeX (Complete) - http://miktex.org/2.9/setup
  (NOTE: Be sure to download the Complete rather than Basic installation)

  Mac OS X: TexLive 2013 (Full) - http://tug.org/mactex/
  (NOTE: Download with Safari rather than Chrome _strongly_ recommended)

  Linux: Use system package manager
```

I use Mac OS X 10.7.5
Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

It's embarrassing how simple the answer is! Just restart Rstudio after installation of MacTeX program. Done, pdf created.

Comment: No need to feel embarassed.  It's not *that* obvious of a solution and it might help someone.